# Efficient way to build CSV table from three MySQL tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, csv

I want to use PHP to build CSV table from data from database. I'm programming app that holds children scoring. My first table only defines children:

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━┓
┃ ID ┃ name ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━┩
│  1 │ John │
│  2 │ Lucy │
│  3 │ Zara │
└────┴──────┘
```

Second defines events, where children can get points

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ID ┃    date    ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│  1 │ 2016-12-31 │
│  2 │ 2017-01-07 │
│  3 │ 2017-01-14 │
│  4 │ 2017-01-21 │
└────┴────────────┘
```

and the third one tell us how many points got child with childID on event with eventID

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ID ┃ eventID ┃ childID ┃ points ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━┩
│  1 │       1 │       1 │     21 │
│  2 │       1 │       2 │     43 │
│  3 │       1 │       3 │      4 │
│  4 │       2 │       1 │      8 │
│  5 │       2 │       2 │     15 │
│  6 │       2 │       3 │     13 │
│  7 │       3 │       1 │     34 │
│  8 │       3 │       2 │     40 │
│  9 │       3 │       3 │     20 │
│ 10 │       4 │       1 │      3 │
│ 11 │       4 │       2 │      7 │
│ 12 │       4 │       3 │      9 │
└────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

Let's say that we have C children and E events, thus table points has C*E rows. Now I want to find the most efficient way to build table like this:

```
     event;John;Lucy;Zara;⋯
2016-12-31;  21;  43;   4;
2017-01-07;   8;  15;  13;
2017-01-14;  34;  40;  20;
2017-01-21;   3;   7;   9;
     ⋮                   ⋱
```

*It can also be row<->col swapped, but I've more events than children.*

But I don't feel comfortable about making C times E queries to database. I've tried generating long and ugly query with PHP but it basically also made C times E subqueries. I also have idea how to build it with only E queries but isn't it possible with only one?

Comment: You'll need to read about two things: `JOIN` queries, and pivoting of tables. This is pretty basic SQL.

Comment: @O.Jones And it will be possible to do only with one query? Because I don't know how to make children names being column headers.

Comment: you could do it with a single query, but it will get complex if you plan to pivot all the tables inside of SQL. I recommend selecting the data through `join` queries and then parsing it out into the format you want in the PHP. When you are done you can just use something like `fputcsv()` to create the CSV document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation which in MySQL you will have to tediously do for every child name. If too many to be feasible (i.e., hundreds), consider using PHP to dynamically build the SQL string.

```sql
SELECT e.date AS `event`, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = 'John' THEN j.points ELSE 0 END) As `John`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = 'Lucy' THEN j.points ELSE 0 END) As `Lucy`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = 'Zara' THEN j.points ELSE 0 END) As `Zara`   
FROM EventChildJoin j
INNER JOIN ChildTable c
   ON j.childID = c.ID
INNER JOIN EventTable e
   ON j.eventID = e.ID
GROUP BY e.date
```

As mentioned, since MySQL does not have a crosstab/pivot method, you must build SQL at the application layer and then pass into the database layer for processing. Here is example with PHP:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);    

    # FIRST FETCH
    $strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ChildTable";
    $STH = $dbh->query($strSQL);
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $strSQL = "SELECT e.date AS `event`, ";    
    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
        $strSQL = $strSQL . " SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = '". row['name'] ."' " .
                            "          THEN j.points ELSE 0 END) As `". row['name'] ."`,";
    }

    $strSQL = " FROM EventChildJoin j".
              " INNER JOIN ChildTable c ".
              "      ON j.childID = c.ID ".
              " INNER JOIN EventTable e ".
              "      ON j.eventID = e.ID ".
              " GROUP BY e.date;";
    $strSQL = str_replace(", FROM", " FROM", strSQL)    # REMOVE COMMA AFTER LAST COLUMN

   # NEXT FETCH
   $STH = null;
   $STH = $dbh->query($strSQL);
   $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ...    
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for now I've 10 children, even so I'd generate that string dynamically, because I want ChildTable to be flexible (I want to add or remove child without need to change anything in PHP code). But teoretically, if I'd have them thousands isn't there way to sum up all that column headers with child names into one command - something like "MySQL, take all these columns from ChildTable"?

Comment: But there is only one column in table. You are referring to *name* values you wish to pivot into new columns. Other databases like SQL Server and Postgres even MS Access have dynamic pivot/crosstab functions not MySQL. For more dynamic reporting neeeds, run code at application layer such as PHP.

Comment: But I mean columns that generates your SQL on 2nd, 3rd and 4th row. Isn't there a way to generate this dynamically directly in SQL, without using PHP to dynamically generate string? Because it costs data to transfer this line SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = 'Zara' THEN j.points ELSE 0 END) As `Zara` let's say thousand times. It'd be better to dynamically generate columns (of the resulting table) in MySQL. Or that's what you've written, that MySQL can't do?

Comment: Understand, SQL is a declarative, special-purpose language designed to retrieve and manipulate data in databases. PHP is a dynamic, scripting, OOP, general-purpose language. Anything declared in an SQL statement including columns in `SELECT` is immutable. You need a pivoting method which MySQL does not maintain. Hence, build string SQL and then pass into MySQL to run.

Comment: See update with PHP dynamic SQL statement build. Notice variables here are mutable as we update *strSQL*, especially in an iterative loop! In SQL variables are static after declaration.